# How to combine two different GroupedStreams in Rx.NET?

Tags: c#, f#, rx.net

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880719/how-to-combine-groupedobservables-in-rx-net) is similar, but it does not apply to my case, since the user needed the merge observable streams from the same IGroupedObservable, while I want to combine streams from different groups.

I have the following structures and streams:

```
type A = {
  Id: int
  Value: int
}

type B = {
  Id: int
  Value: int
}

//subjects to test input, just any source of As and Bs
let subjectA: Subject<A> = Subject.broadcast
let subjectB: Subject<B> = Subject.broadcast

//grouped streams
let groupedA: IObservable<<IGroupedObservable<int, A>> = Observable.groupBy (fun a -> a.Id) subjectA
let groupedB: IObservable<<IGroupedObservable<int, B>> = Observable.groupBy (fun b -> b.Id) subjectB
```

I want to somehow merge the internal observables of A and B when groupedA.Key = groupedB.Key, and get an observable of (A, B) pairs where A.Id = B.Id

The signature I want is something like
`IObservable<IGroupedObservable<int, A>> -> IObservable<IGroupedObservable<int, B>> -> IObservable<IGroupedObservable<int, (A, B)>>` where for all (A, B), A.Id = B.Id

I tried a bunch of combineLatest, groupJoin, filters and maps variations, but with no success.

I'm using F# with Rx.Net and FSharp.Control.Reactive, but if you know the answer in C# (or any language, really) please post it

Comment: Do you want a complete cross join? With the only requirement that a.Id == b.Id?

Comment: Not sure what "complete cross join" means in this context, but yes, I believe so.

Comment: I think `Observable.groupBy` returns an `IObservable<IGroupedObservable<_, _>>`, not just a single `IGroupedObservable<_, _>`, so I assume that's what you're actually trying to combine?

Comment: @brianberns correct, fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a custom operator `GroupJoin` that you could use. It is based on the `Select`, `Merge`, `GroupBy` and `Where` operators:

```
/// <summary>
/// Groups and joins the elements of two observable sequences, based on common keys.
/// </summary>
public static IObservable<(TKey Key, IObservable<TLeft> Left, IObservable<TRight> Right)>
    GroupJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey>(
    this IObservable<TLeft> left,
    IObservable<TRight> right,
    Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
    Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
{
    // Arguments validation omitted
    keyComparer ??= EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    return left
        .Select(x => (x, (TRight)default, Type: 1, Key: leftKeySelector(x)))
        .Merge(right.Select(x => ((TLeft)default, x, Type: 2, Key: rightKeySelector(x))))
        .GroupBy(e => e.Key, keyComparer)
        .Select(g => (
            g.Key,
            g.Where(e => e.Type == 1).Select(e => e.Item1),
            g.Where(e => e.Type == 2).Select(e => e.Item2)
        ));
}
```

Usage example:

```
var subjectA = new Subject<A>();
var subjectB = new Subject<B>();

IObservable<IGroupedObservable<int, (A, B)>> query = subjectA
    .GroupJoin(subjectB, a => a.Id, b => b.Id)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Left.Zip(g.Right, (a, b) => (g.Key, a, b)))
    .GroupBy(e => e.Key, e => (e.a, e.b));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear if this is what you want. So it may be helpful to clarify first with runner code. Assuming the following runner code:

```
var aSubject = new Subject<A>();
var bSubject = new Subject<B>();

var groupedA = aSubject.GroupBy(a => a.Id);
var groupedB = bSubject.GroupBy(b => b.Id);

//Initiate solution

solution.Merge()
    .Subscribe(t => Console.WriteLine($"(Id = {t.a.Id}, AValue = {t.a.Value}, BValue = {t.b.Value}  )"));

aSubject.OnNext(new A() { Id = 1, Value = 1 });
aSubject.OnNext(new A() { Id = 1, Value = 2 });

bSubject.OnNext(new B() { Id = 1, Value = 10 });
bSubject.OnNext(new B() { Id = 1, Value = 20 });
bSubject.OnNext(new B() { Id = 1, Value = 30 });
```

Do you want to see the following output:

```
(Id = 1, AValue = 1, BValue = 10)
(Id = 1, AValue = 2, BValue = 10)
(Id = 1, AValue = 1, BValue = 20)
(Id = 1, AValue = 2, BValue = 20)
(Id = 1, AValue = 1, BValue = 30)
(Id = 1, AValue = 2, BValue = 30)
```

If that's the case, you can get to solution as follows:

```
var solution = groupedA.Merge()
    .Join(groupedB.Merge(),
        _ => Observable.Never<Unit>(),
        _ => Observable.Never<Unit>(),
        (a, b) => (a, b)
    )
    .Where(t => t.a.Id == t.b.Id)
    .GroupBy(g => g.a.Id);
```

I'll caution that there are memory/performance impacts here if this is part of a long-running process. This keeps all `A` and `B` objects in memory indefinitely, waiting to see if they can be paired off. To shorten the amount of time they're kept in memory, change the `Observable.Never()` calls to appropriate windows for how long to keep each object in memory.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve. In my case, I want to match the *latest* A with Id = 1 with the *latest* B with Id = 1 for example, while the old values of A and B with Id=1 can be freed from memory. How would I do that? I'm dont quite get what this Observable.Never is doing, I think.

Comment: @fnzr this is important info that should probably be included in the question. Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66911017/edit) the question and add this info there?

Answer (score 0):

As a start, this has the signature you want:

```
let cartesian left right =
    rxquery {
        for a in left do
        for b in right do
        yield a, b
    }

let mergeGroups left right =
    rxquery {
        for (leftGroup : IGroupedObservable<'key, 'a>) in left do
        for (rightGroup : IGroupedObservable<'key, 'b>) in right do
        if leftGroup.Key = rightGroup.Key then
            let merged = cartesian leftGroup rightGroup
            yield {
                new IGroupedObservable<_, _> with
                    member __.Key = leftGroup.Key
                    member __.Subscribe(observer) = merged.Subscribe(observer)
            }
    }
```

However, in my testing, the groups are all empty. I don't have enough Rx experience to know why, but perhaps someone else does.